# Webscraping off Carmax with selenium and python, can't locate "load more matches" button that is placed inside shadow-root

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Below is my code, I cannot figure out how to get selenium to continue pressing the load more matches button until it shows all 66k results instead of 20-something at a time. I've tried copying the xpath of multiple things, as my understanding of HTML is limited and I'm new to coding.

When copying the xpath of the `"See More Matches"` directly, I get a different error saying `invalid selector`: The result of the xpath expression `"//*[@id="see-more"]/div/hzn-button/text()"` is: `[object Text`]. It should be an element.

[image]

and when I copy the xpath of the `<button class.....>`, I get the error shown below. I'm trying to webscrape and do my first analysis by myself. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
#creating a bot with selenium
#creating a bot with selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib3
import re
import time
import pandas as pd
website = 'https://www.carmax.com/cars/all'
service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path = '/Users/apple/Downloads/chromedriver-mac-arm64/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get(website)
driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="see-more"]/div/hzn-button//button')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="see-more"]/div/hzn-button//button')

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:741, in WebDriver.find_element(self, by, value)
    738     by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    739     value = f'[name="{value}"]'
--> 741 return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:347, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    345 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    346 if response:
--> 347     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    348     response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))
    349     return response

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:229, in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    227         alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    228     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 229 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="see-more"]/div/hzn-button//button"}
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.109); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x0000000102dca004 chromedriver + 4169732
1   chromedriver                        0x0000000102dc1ff8 chromedriver + 4136952
2   chromedriver                        0x0000000102a17500 chromedriver + 292096
3   chromedriver                        0x0000000102a5c7a0 chromedriver + 575392
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000102a97818 chromedriver + 817176
5   chromedriver                        0x0000000102a505e8 chromedriver + 525800
6   chromedriver                        0x0000000102a514b8 chromedriver + 529592
7   chromedriver                        0x0000000102d90334 chromedriver + 3932980
8   chromedriver                        0x0000000102d94970 chromedriver + 3950960
9   chromedriver                        0x0000000102d78774 chromedriver + 3835764
10  chromedriver                        0x0000000102d95478 chromedriver + 3953784
11  chromedriver                        0x0000000102d6aab4 chromedriver + 3779252
12  chromedriver                        0x0000000102db1914 chromedriver + 4069652
13  chromedriver                        0x0000000102db1a90 chromedriver + 4070032
14  chromedriver                        0x0000000102dc1c70 chromedriver + 4136048
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018414ffa8 _pthread_start + 148
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018414ada0 thread_start + 8
```

Comment: if you have web browser  opened by `Selenium` then you could check if it get the same HTML as you expect. Server may send different HTML to different users, different browser, or different devices, etc. You may also check if elements is not inside `<iframe>` because Selenium treads frame as separated page and it needs `switch_to.frame(...)`. Next idea: first try to find `//*[@id="see-more"]`, next try to find `//*[@id="see-more"]/div`,  etc. and you will see which one makes problem. Maybe it needs to add `//` between elements to skip something.

Comment: Last idea: If elements are added by `JavaScript` then `JavaScript` may need time for it - and you may need `time.sleep()` or special functions in Selenium: [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: this page shows me only `Access Denied You don't have permission to access "http://www.carmax.com/" on this server.`. So I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Your button is placed inside shadow-root, to get internal shadow root structure, you should get it's host first and then get shadowRoot property.

Shadow host in current example is element with locator `//*[@id="see-more"]//hzn-button`

`get_shadow_root` function gets shadow root from host, using JS executor.

[More about Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM)

Note: in your case you can just click on element with locator `//*[@id="see-more"]//hzn-button` and not to go inside `shadow-root`.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
timeout = 10
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)

def get_shadow_root(element):
    return driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)

driver.get("https://www.carmax.com/cars/all")
driver.maximize_window()

shadow_host = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="see-more"]//hzn-button')))
see_more = get_shadow_root(shadow_host).find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.hzn-button')
see_more.click()
```